# Appending the dataframe via loop

Tags: scala, apache-spark, group-by, apache-spark-sql

I have created an empty dataframe `var c= emptyDataFrame`

Also, I have dataset with 200+ cols, below is my loop code

```
for (x <- groupcols){
 var t= df.groupBy(x).agg(countDistinct ("ID") as "ID_Count", countDistinct("ID")/df.count as "Percentage")
 t.show 
}
```

t.show gives me table with 3 cols: col a: x, col b: ID_count , col c: Percentage

I want to append the result into the emptyDataFrame

I tried converting the result to string and append the result to string but I am unable to view the result.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a reduce function:

```
val df = groupcols
    .map(g => g.groupBy(x).agg(countDistinct ("ID") as "ID_Count", countDistinct("ID")/y.count as "Percentage")) })
    .reduceLeft((x, y) => x.union(y))
```

Written from scratch without testing, but should work something like this. You don't need an empty dataframe for this. It will union all the results together and you should be able to do a df.show()